# Cordova inAppBrowser Hide / Show in Java Android

Tags: java, android, cordova, phonegap

I am working with Cordova and the inAppBrowser plugin for Android

> https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser

I am trying to control the hardware back button for Android in Java file

InAppBrowserDialog.java

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (this.inAppBrowser == null) {
        this.dismiss();
    } else {
        if (this.inAppBrowser.hardwareBack() && this.inAppBrowser.canGoBack()) {
            // this.inAppBrowser.goBack();
        } else {
            // this.inAppBrowser.closeDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

I do not want it to "goBack" or "closeDialog", I want it to "hide", like you can call it on the Cordova Javascript side

> https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser#inappbrowserhide

```
ref.hide();
```

Hide is ideal so I can call .show if I want without loading the entire page, which is what would happen if I just closed it.

I am looking for a Java command such as

```
 this.inAppBrowser.hide();
```

But I can't seem to find it.

---

**Update**

So the Java code linked to the Codrova .hide Javascript is here

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/8bdbd18d1619e25cf8bdedadf6448ef40b21ea7c/src/android/InAppBrowser.java#L329-L341

```
        else if (action.equals("hide")) {
        this.cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (dialog != null && !cordova.getActivity().isFinishing()) {
                    dialog.hide();
                }
            }
        });
        PluginResult pluginResult = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK);
        pluginResult.setKeepCallback(true);
        this.callbackContext.sendPluginResult(pluginResult);
    }
```

I just can't figure out how to call this Java function from the Java back button function.

---

**Update**

WORKING VERSION provided by JensV

So I edited InAppBrowserDialog.java

I added

```
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaArgs;
import org.json.JSONArray;
```

And added inside the

```
public class InAppBrowserDialog extends Dialog {
```

the following

```
public void hideDialog() {
    CordovaArgs args = new CordovaArgs(new JSONArray());
    try {
        this.inAppBrowser.execute("hide", args, new FakeCallbackContext());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void showDialog() {
    CordovaArgs args = new CordovaArgs(new JSONArray());
    try {
        this.inAppBrowser.execute("show", args, new FakeCallbackContext());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I then created a new java file in the same directory, called

```
FakeCallbackContext.java
```

And placed the following code inside

```
package org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser;

import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.PluginResult;

class FakeCallbackContext extends CallbackContext {

  public FakeCallbackContext() {
    super(null, null);
    
  }

  @Override
  public void sendPluginResult(PluginResult pluginResult) {
    // Do not send an actual result to the webview
    // Perhaps just log the result
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look at the source code and confirmed that the plugin does not expose the `dialog` member which prevents you from directly interacting with it. One way is to expose it via reflection but that seems to hacky to me.

What you can do is to emulate the JS function call directly in Java by calling `execute` on the plugin. In order for that to not have any unexpected issues, we need to provide a `CordovaArgs` and `CallbackContext` instance. `CordovaArgs` is easily faked, but the `CallbackContext` should not interact with the actual webview and attempt to call JS. So I created a wrapper which does nothing when called:

```java
package your.package.name

import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.PluginResult;

class FakeCallbackContext extends CallbackContext {

    public FakeCallbackContext() {
        super(null, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void sendPluginResult(PluginResult pluginResult) {
        // Do not send an actual result to the webview
        // Perhaps just log the result
    }
}
```

Then in order to call the methods from your code you can call execute as follows. I'm assuming that `this.inAppBrowser` is an instance of `InAppBrowser`:

```java
// ...

import org.apache.cordova.CordovaArgs;
import org.json.JSONArray;

// ...


void hideDialog() {
    CordovaArgs args = new CordovaArgs(new JSONArray());
    this.inAppBrowser.execute("hide", args, new FakeCallbackContext());
}

void showDialog() {
    CordovaArgs args = new CordovaArgs(new JSONArray());
    this.inAppBrowser.execute("show", args, new FakeCallbackContext());
}
```

---

**Update**
Added the necessary imports. For reference, I was referring to the "Quick Fix" feature of Intellij / Android Studio. You can press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (Mac:  <kbd>⌥</kbd>  +  <kbd>↵</kbd> ) on a error in the source code (highlighted in red) to apply suggestions to fix that error. This includes and is not limited to missing imports.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am very new to Java, where do I place this code? I placed your "hide" call inside the onBackPressed Java function, so it gets called when the user hits the back button. I tried placing FakeCallbackContext  class both inside onBackPressed and tried just outside of it. Both attempts return a compilation error, unable to find symbol class CallbackContext. Is there a library I need to import? Where would you suggest I place your code?

Comment: The FakeCallbackContext can be placed in it's own file. It's a class, no different from any other.

Comment: I updated my original question to include an attempt at making your suggestion work. would you be able to take a look at it? Thanks.

Comment: @nomaam You're missing the imports for these classes. Android Studio should be able to autofix this.

Comment: when I run it in android studio i get the same errors. what java class would support "extends CallbackContext" ?

Comment: @nomaam updated answer with imports and explanation

Comment: Thank you for your patience. I have updated my edit to show your latest version. However I am receiving a new error on this(null, null);

Comment: @nomaam ah, my bad. It's supposed to be `super(null, null)`

Comment: I had to make some modifications using that android studio auto fix trick you showed me. And it works!!! Thank you so much! I will update my last update with the final version.

Comment: So I need to let Cordova know the hide function was called. Is it possible to send a message to Cordova in the FakeCallBackContext class in the sendPluginResult, something like webView.loadUrl("javascript:cordovafunction('hey');")); I have tried a few variations without success.

Comment: @nomaam this is possible but entirely unrelated to this question. If you can't figure it out, create a new question

Comment: I understand, here it is:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65799899/cordova-sending-data-from-android-java-to-javascript